# Where is the .bashrc file in my cloud9 app ? (Daniel Kehoe's learn-rails tutorial book)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, railsapps

I am trying to set up the configuration in preparation for following Daniel Kehoe's learn-rails tutorial book, but I am having trouble setting up the environment variables.  The book seems to explain how to do it on Mac and Atom but not with cloud9. I am supposed to put the environment variables into a file called ".bashrc" but I don't know where to find this file as it is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it on the left side `Workspace->Setting Icon->Show Hidden Files`, You can click on the left side upper right then click it then it will show a list then you can click `Show Hidden Files`

See the attached images

[image]

then below of the left side tree

[image]

Or you can use [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for the environment variable.

Add Figaro to your Gemfile and `bundle install`:

```
gem "figaro"
```

Figaro installation is easy:

```
bundle exec figaro install
```

This creates a commented `config/application.yml` file. Add your own configuration to this file and you're done!

**Example**

```
# config/application.yml

SENDGRID_USERNAME: "appxxxxxx@heroku.com"
SENDGRID_PASSWORD: "$xxxxxxxxxxxxx@"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: is there also a way to find this file through Atom text editor if i am developing off line? i seem to have the same problem of not being able to find the file there also.

Comment: If you use `figaro gem` then it will work for online offline, everywhere, for the repository you need edit `.gitignore` file to permit transfer file